# GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY difference SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is difference between GEOMETRY and GEOGRAPHY in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read the wonderful manual at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx

> The geometry Data Type
>
> The **geometry data type (planar)**
>   supported by SQL Server conforms to
>   the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC)
>   Simple Features for SQL Specification
>   version 1.1.0.
>
> For more information on OGC
>   specifications, see the following:
>
> ```
> * OGC Specifications, Simple Feature Access Part 1 - Common
> ```
>
> Architecture
>       * OGC Specifications, Simple Feature Access Part 2 – SQL Options
>
> The geography Data Type
>
> The **geography data type (geodetic)**
>   stores ellipsoidal (round-earth) data,
>   such as GPS latitude and longitude
>   coordinates.

It comes down to what model of the earth you're using - a planar or geodetic one.

Answer (score 42):

`GEOMETRY` is for **planar** spatial data (that is, data on a flat surface)

`GEOGRAPHY` is for **terrestrial** spatial data (that is, data on the (curved) surface of the Earth)

See eg [here](http://jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/sql-server-2008-spatial-data-part-1.aspx), [here](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2007/12/sql-server-2008-geography-vs-geometry.html) for more.

Comment: +1 for the plain english description - it's Friday afternoon and I don't even want to look at words like geodetic and ellipsoidal !  :-)